# Detecting touches on an HTML5 in a UIWebView on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

Is it possible to detect touches on an HTML5 in a UIWebView on the iPhone?

Comment: what kind of stuff are you trying to detect with the touches? e.g. hyperlink?

Comment: Yeah, if you need detailed control of touches you're probably better off scraping the page with Xpath and putting the info into actual UI elements. Otherwise, you'll have to start calculating the positions of the objects within the webview.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; there are several ways and frameworks which help you do this:

- [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)
- [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/)
- Using events like ontouchend / ontouchstart / ontouchmove

Both of those mobile frameworks are pretty straight forward, should be able to get going rather quick.

Good luck!