# Online HTML5 sticky sample

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, dom-events

Here is an awesome HTML5 sample http://admixweb.com/demos/posticks/

To test in UIWebView in iOS application, the whole page can be loaded perfectly, but the touch events can not be handled.

Question is why those events can not be handled in the UIWebView (Safari actually)?

Quite new to html5 etc, thanks for any clues or explanations here.

Comment: It doesn't look like HTML5. Just a bunch of divs and whatnot. As for the events, probably programmer error.

Comment: same for this https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_of_contenteditable_and_localstorage_create_a_web_sticky_note?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it's local storage, that's why it's HTML5. That has nothing to do with the events.

They're probably using click events, not 'touchstart' and 'touchend' events. That's probably why your events don't seem to work. The events on iOS fire in a different order than on a regular browser. [This](http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html) might help explain it.

Basically, a regular browser handles these events (in order):

- mousedown
- mousemove
- mouseup
- click

On iOS, sometimes these events get fired all together, which breaks some applications, especially ones that depend on moving stuff. From the link, sometimes mousedown isn't fired when the user touches the screen, but when the user lifts it.  I had a similar problem in a webapp I developed.

The better way to do this is to use touch events for touch-enabled devices, and mouse events for non-touch enabled devices.  This removes the possibility of code getting mashed.

Comment: Yes,totally agreed with your analysis. Just wonder what is the best way to resolve the touch events for UIWebView ? Thanks

Comment: Some answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835231/detecting-touches-on-an-html5-in-a-uiwebview-on-the-iphone